# Ordering sequence of numbers in C

Tags: c

How would I be able to check the ranking of the numbers in first and second sequence and see if there are ordered the same way? And also is there a way to count the number of elements without having the user input it in?

I want to input a sequence of numbers (the length must be even), and what the program should do it split the sequence in half. And for all the elements in the split sequence they should be arranged in a way that for all i, j, 1<=i, j<=n, a[i]<=a[j] if and only if b[i]<=b[j], where n is the length of a sequence.

Basically it checks the order of the first half of the sequence and checks to see if the order is similar in the second half.

```
ex: 
input: 7 5 9 13 12 4 2 25 33 26
seq1: 7 5 9 13 12
seq2: 4 2 25 33 26
Are order equivalent
```

this sequence rank order of 7,5,9,13,12 is 4th,5th,3rd,1st,2nd and the second half also has the same ranking order. Same as if 2,1,5,4 are inputted they are also order equivalent, because seq1 order is 1st largest and 2nd largest same with seq2.

I don't understand the how I would rank the order of the sequences, I was thinking about using bubble sort but then I realized that that it is wrong. I need to split the sequence in half then check the half sequence as they are and see if there the same.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int main(){
    int array[100], n, c, d, swap, first[100], sec[100];
    printf("enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &n)
    printf("enter %d integers:\n", n);
    for(c = 0; c < n; c++)
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);
    //--------------------------------------------------
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("sorted elements in a ascending order\n");
        for(c=0; c<n; c++){ 
            printf("%d ", array[c]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    //place first half of array in first array
        for(c = 0; c< (n/2); c++){
            first[c] = array[c]; 
        }
    //place sec half array in sec array
        int a = 0;
        for(c = (n/2); c < (n); c++ ){
            sec[a] = array[c];
            a++;
        }
    //------------------------------------------print arrays 
        printf("\nfirst\n ");
        for(c = 0; c<(n/2); c++){
            printf("%d ", first[c]);
        }
        printf("\nsec\n ");
        for(c = 0; c<(n/2); c++){
            printf("%d ", sec[c]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        //bubble sort for first half
        for(c = 0; c <(n-1); c++){
            //c = 3;
            for(d=c; d < n; d++){
                if (d > c){
                    break;
                }
                if(first[d] > first[c]){
                    printf(" before d %d", first[c]);
                    swap = first[c];
                    first[d] = first[c];
                    first[c] = swap;
                    printf(" end d %d", first[d]);
                }
                printf(" before d %d", first[c]);
            }
    }
        for(c = 0; c < (n/2); c++ ){
    //----------------------------------------------------print array after sort
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("first array sort %d\n", first[c]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: consider a function `testorder(a,b)` which returns -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b and 1 if a >b.  This would allow you to test the order

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably want to get the input as one string/char array and then parse it. Not sure if c# has anything to help you with this, but it is doable by using the spaces between the numbers to split them up, and then converting the single number char sequences to ints. you then probably want to put the ints in some sort of array or list, whatever your comfortable with, for sorting. after that the algorithm may take some work, and may involve a few arrays but there should be nothing too complicated about it.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Code in C#:

```
Console.Write("input: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var nums = input.Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
if (nums.Count % 2 != 0) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Length must be even.");
}
var seq1 = nums.GetRange(0, nums.Count / 2);
var seq2 = nums.GetRange(nums.Count / 2, nums.Count / 2);
Console.WriteLine("seq1: " + string.Join(" ", seq1));
Console.WriteLine("seq2: " + string.Join(" ", seq2));
bool areEquiv = true;
for (int i = 0; i < seq1.Count && areEquiv; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < seq2.Count && areEquiv; j++) {
        if ((seq1[i] <= seq1[j]) != (seq2[i] <= seq2[j])) {
            areEquiv = false;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Are {0}order equivalent", areEquiv ? string.Empty : "NOT "));
```

Example input and output:

```
input: 7 5 9 13 12 4 2 25 33 26
seq1: 7 5 9 13 12
seq2: 4 2 25 33 26
Are order equivalent

input: 5 6 9 8
seq1: 5 6
seq2: 9 8
Are NOT order equivalent
```